# Codeigniter ORM Datamapper save error

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I'm new to datamapper, i try to save an object using this code

```
$user = new users();
$user->name = $name;
$user->parent = $id_parent;
$user->seq = $seq;
$user->save()
```

codeigniter give this error when executing the code

```
Severity: Warning

Message: sprintf() [function.sprintf]: Too few arguments

Filename: libraries/datamapper.php

Line Number: 4158
```

the data not saved in db, but when i use `$user->check_last_query()` and executing the returned SQL on MYSQL, row inserted.
can someone find out what is the problem here?
thanks.

Comment: can you post your Users model?

Comment: there's nothing else on it except the table name

Comment: What version of datamapper are you using? (what's on that line?) Also, could you post your table schema?